# Cannot get the correct OS grid references on the outside of the map

Tags: qgis

I am using both 50K and 25K Rasters from OS to try to produce smaller scale maps, eg Exmoor, but try as I might I cannot get the OS grid references on the outside of the map grid, the best I have got is on the centimetre or millimetre button to produce figures on the outside of the map, but both X and Y start at 0 not the OS grid reference, I am using CRS ESPG:27700, can anyone help?

Comment: did you ever get an answer to this? I found using
Left(Right(@grid_number,5),2) gives you the result you are looking for. This works as this way...
Right(@grid_number,5) reads the final right numbers in the Northing / Easting - which point to the actual grid reference. Left((),2) then tells QGIS to take the first to numbers of the final five to give your '65' The first one (or two, as the northing can be 7 digits) digits tell you the sheet ref number when taken from the X and Y and concatenated. I.e.. X = 265000 and Y = 365000 would give you X = 2, Y = 3. concat (2,3) = 23 = 'SH' My current ta

Answer (score 1):

The key thing to things to check are the interval and the projection.

[image]

As you can see I've selected 1000m as my interval (with a bigger area you might want to try 5000 and 10000). If your projection isn't set to 27700 (OSGB) then you will end up with weird numbers but you should still see some.

I also set the number format to be `to_int( @grid_number)` to avoid the annoying the decimal places, by selecting `custom` in the **Draw Coordinates** format box, then pressing the `E` button to open the expression editor.

[image]

Comment: Looks good so far, but how do I set the number format please? and how do you manage to put the image onto the answer please?

Comment: Also how do I get the figure back to teens not thousands, and at the moment the top and bottom have come out as 265000 not 65. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can convert the grid number into a string and then modify as you need - try something like  right(  to_string( @grid_number/1000),2)

Comment: I can get into the custom, but unfortunately I am not brilliant on this, what do I change when I am in the E button? And where do I go to change the string for the grid number, sorry to ask again, but a step by step guide would be a big help. Thank you

Comment: I posted a question today that touches on what I think you want to do. http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/186271/print-composer-custom-grid-label-problem

Comment: Hi Can you help with the question above please?

Comment: @Derek - I don't understand the question above :-( just paste right( to_string( @grid_number/1000),2) into the left hand box and hit OK

Comment: Hi when I copy your formula and paste into the LHS on the grid number box I get Parser Error:
syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting COMMA or ')'

Eval Error:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Comment: Not sure what I did in the end but it worked thank you, ( I copied the whole sentence from ":-", then deleted the text letter by letter until I got past "paste" and the space and it worked. I thought I had copied from here in the first place, but apparently not!